# macro to go to struct definition in Julia

Tags: macros, julia

In Julia, I could go directly to the definition of a method by the `@edit` macro as follows:

```
@edit 1 + 2
```

Is there a macro which achieves the same functionality for struct definitions? Something like,

```
@edit SomeType
```

which opens the definition of `SomeType` in an editor.

Answer (score 2):

Try `dump(SomeType)` - see the code below for an example:

```
julia> struct MyStruct
       a::Int
       b::String
       end

julia> dump(MyStruct)
MyStruct <: Any
  a::Int64
  b::String
```

Another option I can think of is to look for the default constructor (which in many cases is the `struct` definition itself), for an example try:

```
edit(DataFrame, fieldtypes(DataFrame))
```

Comment: Thanks. `edit(DataFrame, fieldtypes(DataFrame))` is a good workaround, but doesn't work in many cases. Anyway it would be nice to have `@edit SomeType` like syntax for this. Any reason this wouldn't be possible to implement? Or is it just that it is too much work to implement?

Comment: This is the only workaround I could think of. I was hoping that someone will chip in with another idea. I think this could be a good question to ask on Julia Discourse. For sure it is possible to implement. `methods(DataType)` returns all constructors and one of them must be inside a `struct`.